# How to run Java command through code?

Tags: java

I am trying to execute the below code

```
String command="cmd /c ls";
String location="C:\\project";

final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
     dosCommand + " " + location);
```

I am getting the files, but when I run the **cmd /c java** I didn't get the output.
my Java home is added to environment variables.
When I give Java in command prompt I am getting the Java related files. I am not getting through my program.

Comment: Can we have the code you're asking about?

Comment: Please check the link http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42644 we are able to run "cmd /c dir" but i want to use "cmd /c java"

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are facing. Can you say something more about what results you expect and what you actually get? Do you have any errors from process? Are you printing its error stream? How does your code you try to execute `cmd /c java` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to run a Java program throught command line in your Java program? Try this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("java ...");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Assuming you use Java 1.5 or higher, I'd recommend using ProcessBuilder if you want to execute from a different path. It allows you to easily set the working directory for the process.

```
final Process pr = new ProcessBuilder(
    "java", 
    "-Xms512M",
    "-Xmx1024M",
    "-jar", 
    "your_jar_to_use.jar", 
    "your Java class") 
    .directory(new File("<your directory>")) //Set the working directory to <your directory> 
    .start();
```

Comment: yes you are right, i want to run a java program through command line in java program. I want to give the java command in some particular path. Can you tell how can i go to that path and execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

Or better yet, use the Java Compiler API, as demonstrated in [this article](http://www.javabeat.net/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/) and [this one](http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/).